# How to create a simple audioplayer-device for a single soundeffect

Tags: audio, device, player

How can you create an audio player device which can play a single sound effect when a button is pressed?

A button and the speaker should not be the problem, but the tricky part is, what I have to do with the circuit board, where to save the sound effect and all that stuff.

To power it, I'd use a 9V battery or multiple AA's or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: How long a sound do you want? | and is this a single item or for volume production.||  You can get sound recorder devices with about 5 to 10 seconds recording capability that get sold as toys or reminder recorders. They typically cost a few dollars. I have several hundred of them :-). Where do you live?

Answer (score 2):

You can [buy a board](http://www.electronics123.com/s.nl/it.A/id.1915/.f) that records and playbacks two 20-second messages for about $9:

[image]

There are several other similar items on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

If the sound effect is a short enough duration you could store it in the Flash memory of a microcontroller and then use the microcontroller's PWM timer function to drive the speaker. This [Atmel appnote](http://www.atmel.com/atmel/acrobat/doc1456.pdf) explains how to do it. There are also a plethora of tutorials on the web that explain the concept, including [this recent Halloween themed one](http://www.nerdkits.com/videos/halloween_huffman_audio/) that describes using Huffman coding to compress the audio on the microcontroller!

Power it however you like, it's just a matter of how long you want it to last, and you should probably use a regulator to power the microcontroller at least.

Comment: No need for a regulator if you use a Lithium cell, Li-ion cell, or 1 to 3 AAs/AAAs. Do put a decent bulk capacitor though.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the ChipKit UNO32 - it's a board that's compatible with the Arduino UNO, but takes it to the next level.

Hackaday have used one to make a polyphonic sample device that looks really nice, and simple as well.

> http://hackaday.com/2011/06/08/chipkit-sketch-mini-polyphonic-sampling-synth/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what sound effect you want to play.

It could be as simple as a cheap buzzer + switch, or a 555 timer with output wired to a small speaker.
For more sophisticated sound effects you would probably want a microcontroller, and use PWM or DAC. 
There are a few dsPICs with onboard audio DAC and CODEC peripherals that could produce pretty high quality sound.

Answer (score 0):

Each photo is connected to a webpage. Which if any of these does what you want [Many many many short duration sound recorders](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=10+second+voice+recorder&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1038&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=232pToO_KuqZiQfCyd2fDg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQ_AUoAQ)

Ohio. [10 seconds](http://www.nationalartcraft.com/subcategory.asp?gid=3&cid=72&scid=266)

Module 20 seconds [$6.60](http://www.electronics123.com/s.nl/it.A/id.499/.f)

---

ISD speech recorder ICs do what yo want but may be overkill

[ISD ChipCorderIC's by Nuvoton](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/enu/ProductAndSales/ProductLines/ConsumerElectronicsIC/ISDVoiceIC/ISDChipCorder/Pages/default.aspx).

They have many variants but the simplest ones require little more than the IC to record and playback and can be microcontroller or PC controlled or standalone. 
They say:

- Nuvoton's ChipCorder® is a complete, single chip solution for voice and audio recording and playback. It is designed to offer the highest quality single-chip voice record/playback solutions for embedded applications. Non-volatile and highly integrated, they are ideal solutions for adding voice prompts, alerts, interactive menus, and voice memos to consumer, industrial and security products. Available pre-recording services make it easy to add voice to system design.

[image]

A good start to look at is their [ISD15100 series](http://www.nuvoton.com/NuvotonMOSS/Community/ProductInfo.aspx?tp_GUID=85b55d3a-368d-401b-ac05-15eefdc4d3a5) with datasheet [here](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/enu/ProductAndSales/ProductLines/ConsumerElectronicsIC/ISDVoiceIC/ISDChipCorder/Documents/ISD15100.pdf)

Application example here:

[image]